# How to check if textfield is changed programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an input textfield and I want to check if it changes programmatically or by user input. My code:

```
groupingFormula_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onGrFormulaChange);

function onGrFormulaChange(event:Event):void {
...
```

Edit: Sorry for not being clear. I want to clarify the question. I tried below code:

```
...
else if (event.target.text.charAt(groupingFr.length-1) == "/") {
    trace (event.target.text.charAt(groupingFr.length-1) == "/");
}

else if(lastChar == "/") {
    subunits = 1;
    left_mc.numeric_st.value = 1;
    groupingFormula_txt.text.replace(groupingFormula_txt.text.charAt(groupingFormula.length - 1), "");

    setNumericSt();

}
...
```

This outputs true both ways. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to finish writing the code...

```
groupingFormula_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onGrFormulaChange);

function onGrFormulaChange(event:Event):void {
    trace("user input : " + event.target.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing this. One, you create a class based off `TextField` which has `text` and `htmlText` properties overwritten with watcher functions, like this:

```
class WatchedTextField extends TextField {
    public function set text(value:String):void {
        trace(this.name,'text changed to:',value);
        super.text=value;
    }
    public function set htmlText(value:String):void {
        trace(this.name,'htmlText changed to:',value);
        super.htmlText=value;
    }
```

The other is repeatedly querying `text` property from a given TextField, either in a timer routine, or in an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener:

```
static var allTexts:Dictionary=new Dictionary(); // stores previous texts
targetTF.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkText);
function checkText(e:Event):void {
    var tf:TextField = e.target as TextField;
    if (tf==null) return; // not a textfield - go away
    var oldText:String=allTexts[tf]; // you can do this with dictionaries
    var newText:String=tf.text;
    if (oldText==null) allTexts[tf]=newText; else {
        // store the text if there was none. Or else compare them
        if (oldText!=newText) {
            // changed! alarm! panic! Anyway, do actions
            allTexts[tf]=newText;
        }
    }
}
```

The first way might not catch changes performed via `appendText()` calls, because these too "programmatically" change the text field's text, the second way can put too much strain on your SWF, especially if the text in the target text field is large. There might be more, that didn't come to my mind yet.

Comment: i tried second code, i made a trace, and it didn't detect if text was changed by user input or programmatically. for the first one, i couldn't figure out how i could add eventlistener. thanks for your answer, sorry for my english.

Comment: The first code is designed to not use event listeners, but instead intercept assignments to `text` property. The second one - check if that static var is **NOT** re-initialized each frame, and check if the class cast is properly processed. This requires `e.target` to be of a `TextField` subclass to work.

Comment: could you give more examples about both code? i tried this: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/358647/   and it can't distinguish user input and programmatically change.